# Excessive number of actions/effects/reducers in CRUD application

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm new to Angular and ngxr, and I wonder if my current approach is correct way of using ngrx library.
My project is regular CRUD application. There is bunch of resources to manage.
Let's say that I'm implementing components to manage users.

Currently I have defined following actions:

```
FETCH_USERS // for users list
FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS
FETCH_USERS_FAILURE

FETCH_USER // for given user
FETCH_USER_SUCCESS
FETCH_USER_FAILURE

ADD_USER // add new user
ADD_USER_SUCCESS
ADD_USER_FAILURE

UPDATE_USER // edit existing user
UPDATE_USER_SUCCESS
UPDATE_USER_FAILURE

DELETE_USER // delete user
DELETE_USER_SUCCESS
DELETE_USER_FAILURE
```

As you can see, it's a lot of actions (and obviously there are corresponding action classes, reducers, and effects). And it is only for one resource. Lets say that there are 20 resources to manage, and I wind up with 1000+ "code snippets" just to handle ngrx (300 actions definitions, 300 actions classes, 300 reducers switch-cases, and 100 effects)

My question is, am I over-engineering this? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, this is common. There are Angular CLI schematics to help generate some of this code so you don't have to build it all manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal to have.

There are some tools to help you with this if you'd like:

- [@ngrx/entity](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/entity) - provides basic CRUD reducer helpers and selectors
- [angular-ngrx-data](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data) - provides reducers, services, selectors, ...